# Zoom iFrame/Object Without Cropping

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, iframe

I am trying to embed the iPhone Simulator from http://www.transmog.net into our own site. I have this working very well with a form for the user to fill in the URL, which will then get passed through and display the users site via a mobile browser.

However, the embedded simulator is far too large for our purpose and we would like it to be smaller. I'm currently trying to achieve this by putting the simulator inside an iFrame and using CSS to zoom/transform, or an  and doing the same thing.

However, if I zoom to 50%, as well as reducing the size of the simulator, it's also only displaying 50% and "cropping" the rest off.

Have had a search on here and can't seem to find the answer I am looking for.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: a jsfiddle would help a lot

Comment: Have never used jsfiddle before but have put the relevant information in here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Hm29/1/

It's not running and can't work out why but you can find a link to my problem here: 

http://qsavvyrestaurants.com/sim/preview.html

The top two "examples" are what I have tried to zoom, with the bottom one being the original sized version.

Thanks!

Comment: a jsfiddle is supposed to have some sort of output.. if you use images, you can use an image hosting site to link them into your jsfiddle.. yours doesn't have any output

Comment: Hey Tom please mark one of the answers correct, or else explain why neither meets your needs. That's what motivates the users on this site to take the time to respond to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS won't cascade through iframes (unless they're on the same domain as the host page, and have the `seamless` property) — you would have to instantiate whatever technique you wanted *inside* the iframe for it to take effect on its contents. Sadly, this doesn't look possible using the transmogrifier's customisation settings.

Comment: Not necessarily trying to do it solely through CSS. Essentially is there anyway I can "shrink" the content of a frame/or something like a frame?

Comment: `zoom` is a shorthand for `transform`'s ability to scale content. Essentially, this is very much CSS stuff. But the point I'm making is that iframes on different domains won't allow you to tamper with their contents — whether it's HTML, CSS or JS — so even if there were, for example, an HTML solution for scaling contents, it wouldn't help you because the rendered content is locked away from your code on their domain. This is why you have a limited number of config settings to pass through: because there is no other way of affecting the contents.

Comment: in short, frames is a bad idea

Comment: @abbood Not necessarily — for nesting web pages with their own discreet contexts, they're incredibly useful: the service mentioned by the OP wouldn't be possible without them. Other everyday pieces of web functionality like YouTube embeds, Facebook data sharing, and Disqus comments all make it very easy to include another service's functionality without compromising yours or their security. But as a result of that security, you can't tamper with the code within (or without!) the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give some pointers and add comments to each pointer.

There are several options depending on how much you want to invest in fixing this problem.. but then again it seems like a key offering in your [site](http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/) so I think it's worth putting some time into it.

---

**First Option:** you create an **svg** version of what the iphone frame looks like:

- if you don't know what an SVG is, it's basically a vector graphic that doesn't lose quality when you zoom in and out.. think about it as text on this screen.. you don't see the text pixelating when you zoom in do you?)
- you can include the svg in a div and give it the css style: `position: relative`.
- within the above div, put another div and set the css style as `position:absolute` then give it left and top x and y coordinates relative to the parent div.
- Don't use px, use ems instead. Pixels are less predictable when you zoom in/out (zooming in and out is almost like having your content displayed on different screen resolutions.. but let's not get into that)

---

**Second Option:** use **bitmap**

- similar to the one above.. but instead of using an SVG depiction of the iphone.. you can just use a bitmap.. and then set it as a background and pretty much use the same technique as above..
- the problem with this solution is that as users zoom in and out.. you'll see some image quality loss (I can already see it with yours.. zoom 500% into it and you'll see the edges pixelating (ie look rough on the edges)). Again, if this was my site, I'd work hard to make it look good. HTML5 gives you all the power to do that.

---

**Definite Option:** stay away from **iframes**.. it's a much harder option and it's benefits aren't applicable to your situation.